# Ranking words dictionary order in C

Tags: c

I try to rank words entered according to dictionary order. But it gives error. I think I do something wrong while using the function. Can you tell me what is wrong?

```
void rank(char word[][100], int size)
{
    int i,j;
    char temp[100];
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    for(j=0;j<size;j++)
    {
        if(strcmp(word[j],word[j+1])>0)
        {
            strcpy(temp,word[j]);
            strcpy(word[j],word[j+1]);
            strcpy(word[j+1],temp);
        }
    }

    printf("First word: %s\nLast word:  %s",word[0],word[size-1]);
}

int main()
{
    char word[100][200];
    int i=0;

    while(strlen(word[i-1])!=4)
    {
        printf("enter word: ");
        scanf("%s",word[i]); 
        i++;
    }  

    rank(word,i);
}
```

Comment: replace `j+1` with `i`

Comment: When `j` is equal to `size-1`, you are comparing and swapping with `word[j+1]` which is `word[size]` which is beyond the end of the `word` array. So `j<size` should be `j<size-1`.

Comment: That's not how it works! You tell us **what** is wrong and we tell you _why_ and how to correct it. See [ask]

Comment: I am afraid your code wont work. Check where you declared "word" they do not have consistent signature. Using strlen on "word" when it is empty. If you initially set "i" to zero, and and remove 1 from it you will have -1. You cant index array with that. Just take time off and learn C/programming  basic.

Comment: It is a bubble sort question. Nothing to do with dictionaries. But it's far worse than the errors commented - take a look at the chaos in `main`. First, using uninitialised variable. Next, array is not the same as function is expecting. Next, `word[i-1]` is *undefined behaviour* on the first iteration when `i = 0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a few warnings and mistakes.

```
$ gcc main.c 
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:35:10: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘rank’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     rank(word,i);
          ^
main.c:5:6: note: expected ‘char (*)[100]’ but argument is of type ‘char (*)[200]’
 void rank(char word[][100], int size)
```

And some array is out of bounds: `while(strlen(word[i-1])!=4)` A working example is similar to your code. I used `do...while` to work around the segfault and adjusted the loop counters so that you don't get out of bounds.

```
void rank(char word[][200], int size){
    char temp[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; ++i) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < size; ++j) {
            if (strcmp(word[i], word[j]) > 0) {
                strcpy(temp, word[i]);
                strcpy(word[i], word[j]);
                strcpy(word[j], temp);
            }
        }
    }
    printf("First word: %s\nLast word:  %s\n", word[0], word[size - 1]);
}

int main() {
    char word[100][200];
    int i = 0;
    do {
        printf("enter word: ");
        scanf("%s", word[i]);
        i++;

    } while (strlen(word[i - 1]) != 4);
    rank(word,i);
    return (0);
}
```

Test

```
 $ ./a.out 
enter word: Superman
enter word: Batman
enter word: Wolverine
enter word: Cyclops
enter word: Thor
First word: Batman
Last word:  Wolverine
```